Using the Query function in Google Sheets to QUERY a range and find matches to a range of cells
I have a sheet with a large array of data in google-sheet. I want to QUERY data and match one column of that data to values in an array of cells
I have used various variations of the formula and only get matching data from W14, not the range W14:W
I have tried
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(UNFILTERED!A14:W, "SELECT A WHERE Q MATCHES '"&W14:W&"'"))

=(QUERY(UNFILTERED!A14:W, "SELECT A WHERE Q MATCHES '"&W14:W&"'")

=(QUERY(UNFILTERED!A14:W, "SELECT A WHERE Q MATCHES '"&$W14:$W&"'")


Is this about google-sheet or which spreadsheet are you using? Please tag accordingly

It appears that you are expecting that query will look for a match in each row of Column Q and the equivalent row of column W. That is not how query works; query looks for a single matching value (say cell W14"). OTOH, it seems that you are looking for a formula that returns Column A if Column Q matches Column W; an IF  wrapped in an Arrayformula might be enough. Please provide sample data and the expected outcome.
